# Prototype и __proto__ что это вообще такое?

Tags: javascript, наследование, ecmascript

Наткнулся на такую картинку:

[image]

На картинке видно, что у нас есть какая-то функция(я так понимаю конструктор, тут бы я тоже хотел какого-то пояснения). У нее есть 2 свойства, которые ведут на Foo.prototype и на Function.prototype. Вопрос сформулировать тяжко, потому что я не понимаю, что это за 2 разных prototype. Можете разжевать?

Comment: Думаю, разжевать это в кратком ответе будет нелегко, потому что это довольно фундаментальные вещи для JS. Возможно, лучше вам будет прочитать что-то развёрнутое, например, этот раздел c подразделами: https://learn.javascript.ru/prototypes

Comment: Уже перечитывал не 1 раз все из этого раздела, но понимание так и не приходит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция является объектом, а у всех объектов, есть скрытое свойство, значением которого является объект-прототип, на основе которого он создан.

Для функций, таким прототипом является объект `Function.prototype`.

---

Также, у каждой **функции** есть свойство `.prototype`.

Если использовать функцию в качестве конструктора (вызвать с оператором `new`), значение этого свойства будет использовано в качестве прототипа, для создаваемого объекта.

Comment: То есть, когда я создаю новый экземпляр объекта через функцию(с именем foo) конструктор (вызванную через оператор new), этот объект будет иметь в качестве прототипа foo.prototype, а не Function.prototype?

Comment: @Torin_21, да, именно так, проверить это ты можешь следующим образом `Object.getPrototypeOf(new foo()) === foo.prototype`

Comment: Стало намного понятнее, спасибо!